# Prioritize routes in NetworkManager when using custom IP with DHCP fallback

Tags: linux-networking, networkmanager

I'm using network manager to set a custom IP address, but also keeping DHCP activated in case I connect my headless device to another network, I automatically sets the default gateway and everything. However, I want to prioritize my custom IP over the DHCP-generated one.

This is my config:

```
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         192.168.1.33/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   yes
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
```

Which creates the following routing table:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.33 metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s25 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.107 metric 100
```

But I want the `src 192.168.1.33` route to have a lower metric, and the other one to be used as a fallback. Is this possible using nmcli (NetworkManager)?